# Segmentation rules for non latin based languages like Chinese, Japanese

Tags: xml, localization, rules

While exploring globalsight.com ,I came across the segmentation rules(link).It uses full stop(.) as a language delimiter. which segmentaion rules can we use for segment the 
non latin based Languages for which a dot(.) mean something other than a delimiter or for the languages which don't have any delimiters
Example –Chinese,Japanese and Korean

What are the language segmentation rules used for these “non latin”(Chinese,Japanese)  languages? How are the segmentation  rules developed ?

Thanks in advance,
Manjushree

Comment: For the above asked question,we want which segmentation rules can we used for chinese and korean languages which are "non-latin languages"

Answer (score 1):

Japanese uses [kinsoku shori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinsoku_shori). Not sure about the other two though.

Answer (score 1):

Trados, the leading translation memory application, uses the following segmentation rules:

For Japanese and Chinese:

Full Stop: `。`

Colons:  `：:`

Punctuation: `？！?!`

Comment: Can you please provide more detailed explanation.